# "ВперемеШку" или "вперемеЖку"?

Tags: орфография

В текстах встречается и та, и другая форма написания слова: и "вперемеШку", и "вперемеЖку". Как же все-таки правильно?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Правильно писать "вперемеЖку", поскольку это слово образовано от глагола "перемеЖаться".
Пример: *"На полке лежали вперемежку книги на русском и английском языке".*
Однако слово "вперемеШку" тоже существует (эти два слова - паронимы) - проверочное слово "перемешивать". Оно употребляется, когда автор хочет подчеркнуть то, что предметы были перемешаны.
Пример: *"Блюдо кхечеди - это рис вперемешку с чечевицей".*

Answer (score 5):

Рассуждения Shirogane совершенно верны, однако вывод делается, мягко говоря, странный. На основании чего вы признаёте форму *вперемежку* правильной? На самом деле это, конечно же, именно два слова, а не две формы, и оба они фиксируются словарями. Поэтому оба написания верны. Следует при этом помнить, что оба наречия помечаются в словарях как разговорные.

Answer (score 5):

Интересная пара.
Все правильно тут сказано, возможны обе формы: от "межа", "межевать" и от "мешать" (в значении "смешивать"). Первый вариант говорит об относительном порядке в чередовании  составляющих, наличии границы между ними, второй - о полном беспорядке.
Но! В большинстве случаев никакой контекст не поможет. Дело в том, что разделить значения очень часто бывает невозможно.
Хорошо, когда "за окном поезда мелькали пшеничные поля вперемеЖку с овсами" или "в мешке была пшеница вперемеШку с овсом".
А если "На полке стояли книги: справочники впереме?ку c детективами", то тут не то что автор, сам хозяин полки не скажет, что у него там происходит - межевание или смешивание.

Да, "две формы" здесь совсем не означает, что это две формы *одного* слова.

Исходя из исторически сложившегося употребления, все подобные спорные случаи я бы писал через Ж.

Answer (score 3):

Здесь надо смотреть контекст. В институте был у нас пример с "вперемежку", все засыпались. Все так, как написано выше: если "перемеЖались", то "вперемеЖку", если "перемешались", то "вперемешку". Например, *в лесу росли вперемежку березы и осины.*

Comment: Интересно, а почему березы и осины не могут перемеШаться? Мы же говорим "смеШанные леса", а не смеЖенные.